# Add or update an array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I created an array like:

```
myarr: [ 
    { name:'London', population:'7000000' },
    { name:'Munich', population:'1000000' }
]
```

At some point I need to add some new elements to the array, but first I need to check if element with the same name already exists. If yes, the value must be updated. If no, the new element must be created and added. If the value in new element equals zero and the element exists, it must be removed from the array.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: We can improve on your attempt, but we (some of us anyway) will not write the code for you from scratch

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. You are confusing JavaScript object literals (a construct of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). I will edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Besides that, you haven't asked a question.

Comment: @ExplosionPills User Krasimir did it.

Comment: I actually think this is a reasonable question. Although OP hasn't posted details of his/her coding attempts, I don't see why this should be considered off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick http://jsfiddle.net/tcwqV/

```
var arr = [ 
    { name:'London', population:'7000000' },
    { name:'Munich', population:'1000000' }
]

var addNewElement = function(arr, newElement) {
    var found = false;
    for(var i=0; element=arr[i]; i++) {
        if(element.name == newElement.name) {
            found = true;
            if(newElement.population === 0) {
                arr[i] = false;
            } else {
                arr[i] = newElement;
            }            
        }
    }
    if(found === false) {
        arr.push(newElement);
    }
    // removing elements
    var newArr = [];
    for(var i=0; element=arr[i]; i++) {
        if(element !== false) newArr.push(element);
    }
    return newArr;
}

arr = addNewElement(arr, {name: 'Paris', population: '30000000'});
console.log(arr);
arr = addNewElement(arr, {name: 'Paris', population: '60000000'});
console.log(arr);
arr = addNewElement(arr, {name: 'Paris', population: 0});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this

```
function myFunction(myarr, item) {
    var found = false;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < myarr.length) {
        if (myarr[i].name === item.name) {
            // Do the logic (delete or replace)
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    // Add the item
    if (!found)
        myarr.push(item);

    return myarr;
}
```